CVE-2023-28736 Buffer overflow in some Intel(R) SSD Tools software
I am running: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
mdadm: 4.1-5ubuntu1.2  amd64  tool to administer Linux MD arrays (software RAID)
Endpoint security is reporting an app vulnerability, severity high: CVE-2023-28736 and CVE-2023-28938 severity medium.
Recommendation: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/security-center/advisory/intel-sa-00690.html
mdadm-4.2-rc2 or later
When I run apt update no updates available.
Will there be an update available via de Ubuntu repository?
Thanks,
Kind Regards,
Rob

Did you check the Ubuntu CVE Tracker? This kind of question is exactly what that tool is for.

This question is similar to: How can I tell if a CVE has been fixed in Ubuntu's repositories?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
